# Dgrid Editor using Textarea for multiple lines input

Tags: javascript, dojo, textarea, dgrid

Below is the code snippet for my Dgrid's column. I tried to use the TextArea editor plugin to input multiple lines. However every time when I tried press enter for the second line the editor is closed and out of edit-mode.

```
var columns: [{ field: 'Name', 
                label: 'Name', 
                sortable: false, 
                editor: "textarea", 
                editOn: "dblclick" }]
```

[image]

My questions are:

1. Can anyone advice how to overwrite the keyboard event for Editor plugin? e.g. "enter" key for this case
2. If the keyboard event "enter" is overwritten, what is the best way to tell the editor to exit edit-mode? e.g. mouse-click any area outside of the textarea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `dimissOnEnter`. If you set that to `false` when initializing your editor, then pressing enter will not exit edit mode of a textarea